# MySQL Workbench. data shows in gibberish instead of hebrew

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, workbench

When connecting to my server from my laptop and looking at a certain table in the DB. All the data is in gibberish instead of Hebrew.

But when I go to the website that is connected to the DB, everything is fine and I can see the data in Hebrew.

So the only problem I have is with MySQL Workbench.

I need help fast!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you connected to the same database from workbench or is it a local copy?

Comment: try changing character set, before querying. something like `SET NAMES 'utf8'`

Comment: FYI utf8 did not work. but latin1 did.

Comment: If `latin1` worked, you have worse problems.  The `latin1` character set does _not_ include Hebrew characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql every client has connection-related character set and collation system variables. Since MySQL workbench is essentially a client that connects to the database, it also has a connection related character set and collation which happens to fail to display hebrew characters. You can change the connection-related character set anytime by running this query:

```
SET NAMES 'charset_name' COLLATE 'collation_name'
```

which your website is probably doing to connect with correct encoding. 
you can find additional information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)